# Scheduling Jobs with python

Tags: python, schedule

I want to schedule two jobs that start at different times. The first job takes a lot of time so i have to cancel it at a certain hour in order to pause the execution of the script for a while and then run the second scheduled job, but i didn't make it to cancel the first one, it keeps running and the second job never get executed.

I've been trying this :

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import schedule

def job1():
   liat = get_LI_AT()
   for doc in db.collection_linkedin.find():
   try:

    if main_scrap.calculate_time(doc['Link']) >= 1:
        rslt = main_scrap.update_company(doc['Link'], liat)
        print(rslt)
        time.sleep(1)

   except:
        print("check ", doc['Link'])
        pass


def job2():
   liat = get_LI_AT()
   main_scrap.companies_scraping(liat)

scheduler1 = schedule.Scheduler()

j = scheduler1.every().day.at('7:30').do(job1)

scheduler2 = schedule.Scheduler()

scheduler2.every().day.at('14:30').do(job2)

while True:

   while datetime.now().time() > dt.time(7) and datetime.now().time() < dt.time(12):
      scheduler1.run_pending()
      time.sleep(1)

  scheduler1.cancel_job(j)

   while datetime.now().time() > dt.time(14) and datetime.now().time() < dt.time(18):
    scheduler2.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
  scheduler2.clear()

  time.sleep(5)
```

also this :

```
schedule.every().day.at('7:30').do(job1)  
schedule.every().day.at('14:30').do(job2)

while True:

   if datetime.now().time() > dt.time(7) and datetime.now().time() < dt.time(12):
      schedule.run_pending()
      time.sleep(1)

   elif datetime.now().time() > dt.time(14) and datetime.now().time() < dt.time(18):
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
 

   time.sleep(5)
```

i used until also :

```
schedule.every().day.until("12:00").do(job)
schedule.every().day.until("18:00").do(job)

while True:

   if datetime.now().time() > dt.time(7) and datetime.now().time() < dt.time(12):
      schedule.run_pending()
      time.sleep(1)

   elif datetime.now().time() > dt.time(14) and datetime.now().time() < dt.time(18):
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
 

   time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You could perhaps also run the first job in a thread, so it will not block the execution of the second one. See https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Comment: @schilli thx for your reply, i need to cancel the first one .. I Want to run it juste between 7 am and 12am

Answer (score 0):

Run your large job1 in a thread, otherwise it will block your main thread and schedule cannot work (and start the second task).
Work in job1 until you reach your end time

```
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt, time as t

import schedule


def job1():
    end_time = t(18)
    while dt.now().time() < end_time:
        print("Job 1 working...")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Time for job 1 is over")


def job2():
    print("Job 2 working...")


def job1_executor():
    threading.Thread(target=job1).start()


schedule.every().day.at('07:30').do(job1_executor)
schedule.every().day.at('14:30').do(job2)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: sorry for the late  reply,  thx for your answer this brought me an idea  of stopping the execution inside the 1st function itself and schedule it like usual  hhhh